# Overlapping line from smaller disaply in dualhead mode

Tags: unity, gnome, ati, multiple-monitors, dualhead

I have a problem on both gnome shell and unity that is best described with the following photo:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FswLb.jpg

This is my external monitor. It's a FHD monitor and my laptop monitor is 1366x768 px The white line on the left side pointed to by the green arrow is supposed to be on the laptop screen but is instead showing up on the external monitor. They overlap so to say (It's a maximized application on laptop monitor). Like I said... the problem exists on both unity and gnome shell (I had regular ubuntu installed before today, now it's "Ubuntu Gnome"). My graphics card is amd radeon 7670m or 7770m not sure right now. The drivers are open source one I have some problems with the proprietary ones so I could not test what happens with them. Also, my external monitor is set to primary... but it also happens when the laptop display is primary.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem goes away when I use proprietary amd drivers. Which do not cause some other issues anymore so I can use them now instead of the open source ones.